# What is best pointer/reference type when returning member possibly allocated on the stack in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

So to illustrate my question I have made an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct A
{
  void doSomething (){
      cout << "Something\n";
  }
};


struct B
{
  A a;

  A *getA ()
  {
    return &a;
  }
};


int
main ()
{

  B *b = new B ();
  A *a = b->getA ();


  // POINT 1
  if (nullptr != a)
    {
      a->doSomething ();
    }

  delete b;
  b = nullptr;

  // POINT 2
  if (nullptr != a)
    {
      a->doSomething ();
    }

  return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs without errors on my machine, but if you inspect the code, really there is a problem of a dangling pointer on the lines following the comment marked "POINT 2".

Since `b` was deleted, then `a` is now invalid (since it was deleted by dtor   of `b`).

So I could use a shared pointer to remedy this, but that would keep the instance of `a` around even after `b` was deleted, and also I would not be able to allocate `a` on the stack. These are two things I want to avoid. Instead I simply want to know if `a` is still valid.

I could also have used a unique pointer but then I could only have one single instance of `a` which is not what I want either, I want many copies of the pointer to `a`.

So is there some existing pointer/reference type that would allow me to do this? Are there any reason why this is a good/bad idea?

Comment: Just don't use raw pointers at all. Rather use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to make ownership of instances clear.

Comment: There is no quick and easy fix. If you want to know the state of `a`'s validity you have to keep that information *somewhere*. An object cannot inform you of the current state of it's lifetime, it would need to be alive to interrogate it about it's current state.

Comment: "I could use a shared pointer to remedy this, but that would keep the instance of a around even after b was deleted" Not if `getA()` returned a `weak_ptr<A>`.

Comment: If you want `a` to share ownership of `b`'s `a` then you need a `shared_ptr` otherwise you can use a `weak_ptr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just discovered the wonders of ownership semantics :)

How to solve this problem depends on the design of your application: what you need and what you are trying to achieve.

In this case, if you really want to share ownership of an object, use [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) which keeps a reference count of how many pointers are left, so that the last deletes the object; possibly [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) if you only need to check if the object is still alive but don't want to keep it alive longer than needed.

However, do note that (ab)using shared pointers may be a sign of a bad design.

---

By the way, your `A a;` member is not allocated in the stack (i.e. the title is wrong).

Comment: Yes, I want to use RIIA but still be able to safely access members outside the class. Maybe that is bad design :/

Comment: @LennartRolland In that case, simply put the member in a `std::shared_ptr`. If you really want to avoid the allocation/indirection, proceed as @Slava suggests. But yeah, I would seriously reconsider the design. Most things can be solved without relying on shared ownership.

Comment: You are right that A is not allocated on stack here- it is allocated where B is allocated right? so it could possible be allocated in stack but not in this example.

Comment: @LennartRolland Indeed, that `a` is a member of `B`, so wherever you allocate an instance of `B`, there is where the member will be. In this case, since you wrote `new B`, that would be the free store (the heap).

Comment: Forget stack and heap. Talk about storage duration instead.

Answer (score 3):

Only viable solution using standard library that come in mind is to use [std::weak_ptr()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) - it will allow to check object validity without holding it's ownership. That comes with price - you have to maintain ownership of it with `std::shared_ptr`. Though it is possible to create `std::shared_ptr` to an object with automatic storage duration and noop deleter I would do that only if I really need that as such method is error prone and defeats the purpose of a smart pointer.

Comment: @Acorn I understand, I mentioned that for OP's concern that using `std::shared_ptr` will eliminate ability to create that object with automatic storage duration (ie on the stack).

Comment: Yeah, I understood it too late (deleted the comment), sorry.

Comment: @Acorn nothing to be sorry about

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to *not expose `a`*.

Your `B` is the interface. Give it the functions you need to perform. Have it go on to invoke whatever it needs to invoke on the `a` in order to make that happen.

Then remove `getA()`, and make `a` private.

Now it's completely encapsulated and the calling scope cannot arse around with it like this!

No need for pointers or dynamic allocation; just good, old-fashioned OOP.